# Tensorflow (Keras API) `model.fit` method returns "Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor" error

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am using gaussian noise per the `tf.random.normal` method (or `K.random_normal` via the `keras` API).

It is used from within a custom `tensorflow` `Layer`, which, in turn, is used by a custom `Model`.

For some reason, everything works as intended when calling the layer / model directly, or when using a custom training loop via `tf.GradientTape()`, but it throws a puzzling error when attempting to use the `fit` method instead.

It appears to have something to do with inferring the batch dimension, which presents as `None` when calling the `fit` method.

I suspect this has something to do with compilation and symbolic tensors vs. eager tensors, but I'm none-the-wiser as to how this would actually be resolved?

I've tried to strip the problem down to a minimal example that reproduces the issue:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras import models
import tensorflow as tf

class Demo(models.Model):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        # batch gives "2" when called directly or via GradientTape()
        # gives "None" when called via fit
        batch = K.int_shape(inputs)[0]
        dim = K.int_shape(inputs)[1]
        noise = tf.random.normal(shape=(batch, dim), mean=0.0, stddev=1.0)
        # manually specifying the batch dimension does work, e.g.
        # noise = tf.random.normal(shape=(2, dim), mean=0.0, stddev=1.0)
        return inputs * noise

test_data = np.array([[1., 2., 3., 4.], [5., 6., 7., 8.]])

tester = Demo()
tester.compile(optimizer='adam')

# manual calling works
print(test_data - tester(test_data))

# but calling fit does not
tester.fit(x=test_data)
# raises: TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor.
# Contents: (None, 4). Consider casting elements to a supported type.
```

Any suggestions for what the problem might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `call` method, instead of using `keras.backend` to get `batch` and `dim`, use tensorflow directly.

```
batch = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
dim = tf.shape(inputs)[1]
```