# OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function for a customized model

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to implement "attention is all you need" paper to time series with a few tweaks, but I'm getting this error:

> OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function.

Code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

class Attention(tf.keras.layers.Layer):

    def __init__(self, dk, dv, num_heads, filter_size):
        super().__init__()
        self.dk = dk
        self.dv = dv
        self.num_heads = num_heads
        
        self.conv_q = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(dk * num_heads, filter_size, padding='causal')
        self.conv_k = tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(dk * num_heads, filter_size, padding='causal')
        self.dense_v = tf.keras.layers.Dense(dv * num_heads)
        self.dense1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(dv, activation='relu')
        self.dense2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(dv)
        
    def split_heads(self, x, batch_size, dim):
        x = tf.reshape(x, (batch_size, -1, self.num_heads, dim))
        return tf.transpose(x, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        batch_size, time_steps, _ = tf.shape(inputs)
        
        q = self.conv_q(inputs)
        k = self.conv_k(inputs)
        v = self.dense_v(inputs)
        
        q = self.split_heads(q, batch_size, self.dk)
        k = self.split_heads(k, batch_size, self.dk)
        v = self.split_heads(v, batch_size, self.dv)
        
        mask = 1 - tf.linalg.band_part(tf.ones((batch_size, self.num_heads, time_steps, time_steps)), -1, 0)
        
        dk = tf.cast(self.dk, tf.float32)
        
        score = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(q, k, transpose_b=True)/tf.math.sqrt(dk) + mask * -1e9)
        
        outputs = tf.matmul(score, v)
        
        outputs = tf.transpose(outputs, perm=[0, 2, 1, 3])
        outputs = tf.reshape(outputs, (batch_size, time_steps, -1))
        
        outputs = self.dense1(outputs)
        outputs = self.dense2(outputs)
        
        return outputs

class Transformer(tf.keras.models.Model):
    """
    Time Series Transformer Model
    """
    def __init__(self, dk, dv, num_heads, filter_size):
        super().__init__()

        self.attention = Attention(dk, dv, num_heads, filter_size)
        self.dense_sigma = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
    
    def call(self, inputs):
        outputs = self.attention(inputs)
        sigma = self.dense_sigma(outputs)
        
        return sigma

Mymodel= Transformer(3,3,4,3)

Mymodel.compile(loss="mean_squared_error",
    optimizer=keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4),)

Mymodel.fit(X_train,Y_train,epochs=10,batch_size=32)
#X_train & Y_train are numpy array with shape ( batch_size , timesteps , no.of features )
```

Full Error :

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: in user code:

    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py:855 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    <ipython-input-20-56419dd4aeb6>:61 call  *
        outputs = self.attention(inputs)
    <ipython-input-3-a936077354d3>:24 call  *
        batch_size, time_steps, _ = tf.shape(inputs)
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:520 __iter__
        self._disallow_iteration()
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:513 _disallow_iteration
        self._disallow_when_autograph_enabled("iterating over `tf.Tensor`")
    /usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py:491 _disallow_when_autograph_enabled
        " indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.".format(task))

    OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over `tf.Tensor` is not allowed: AutoGraph did convert this function. This might indicate you are trying to use an unsupported feature.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that in graph mode, for unpacking a tensor it tries to iterate over result. Anyway, you may use this instead:

```
batch_size = tf.shape(inputs)[0]
time_steps = tf.shape(inputs)[1]
```

My first recommendation was using `.shape`, however, I modified my answer because of this hint from TensorFlow docs [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/shape):

> `tf.shape(x)` and `x.shape` should be identical in eager mode. Within `tf.function`, not all dimensions may be known until execution time. Hence when defining custom layers and models for graph mode, prefer the dynamic `tf.shape(x)` over the static `x.shape`.

Comment: Thanks, it worked . However, when I tried to predict the model 

    predictions = Mymodel.predict(X_test)

I got this error

>     TypeError: Failed to convert object of type <class 'tuple'> to Tensor. Contents: (None, -1, 4, 3). Consider casting elements to a
> supported type.

Is this still a shape issue?

Comment: Is your X_test  a tuple? I think it is not shape issue. It is related to X_test. Please tell me output of `type(X_test)` and `print(X_test.shape)`.

Comment: no, it's np array just like X_train
Here are the outputs 
(1505, 10, 3)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Comment: Please change the line inputs.shape to `batch_size=inputs.shape[0]` and `time_steps=inputs.shape[1]` and see if anything changes.

Comment: following this answer here :https://stackoverflow.com/a/62544325/13502208
it works fine! , but the shape of the prediction is (1505, 10, 1) and it suppose to be (1505,1)

Comment: You may add a `Flatten` layer, before `Dense` layer to avoid getting timestep dimension in output.